# Bad request converting curl http request to Java

Tags: java, rest, http, curl, resttemplate

I've the following request with curl that talks to Microsoft Azure services without a problem.

```
curl --request POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token --data 'client_id=fe37...06-566f5c762ab2&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=tPv..dQfqomaG&scope=mail.read&code=OAQABAAIA...gAA'
```

Here is the java code that is throwing Bad Request exception:

```
 public String getToken(String authCode){

        try {

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

            String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
            headers.add("client_id", "fe3..b2");
            headers.add("client_secret", "tP..aG");
            headers.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
            headers.add("code", authCode);
            headers.add("scope", "mail.read");


            HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);


        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

I've also tried adding the --data section in to parameters object and I receive the same problem. I am using RestTemplate but I am open for other suggestions.

I appericiate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that problem is that in `curl` example you pass these parameters inside POST body, while in your java code you use headers instead. Try change it to usage of body params of `entity` object:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();     

body.add("client_id", "fe3..b2");
// ... rest params

// Note the body object as first parameter!
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, new HttpHeaders());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send these parameters in the request entity formatted as form url encoded and also set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Your body can be a string (according to your example):

```
String data = "client_id=fe37...06-566f5c762ab2&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=tPv..dQfqomaG&scope=mail.read&code=OAQABAAIA...gAA";
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(data);
```

Set a content type header:

```
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

(Actual implementation depends on the library you use)